# Quoting the page of one my reference document in the title of a figure

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I have inserted a figure in my LaTeX document, and this figure comes from a document referenced in my bibliography. The problem is that this latter document has many pages, so I would like to quote in the title of my figure in which page of the document we can find it. I am using `\bibliographystyle {acm}`. Would that be possible to do?

This is what I have written in LaTex:

```
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\capstart  
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Pictures/blablabla.pdf}
\caption{On, based on \cite{as}}
\label{fig:On}
\end{figure}
```

And this is what appears in my PDF Document below my figure:

> "Figure 2.1: On, based on [4]"

I would like to have this (or something similar):

> "Figure 2.1: On, based on [4 p.38]"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think the solution to the possible duplicate above should solve your problem. If not, please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yeah, you were totally right. With the already provided solution, I have done what I wanted. Thank you very much!!!